# How to show tooltip default in angular without hover?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I need to make a tooltip to be in default and it should not come only in hover over it.. For instance in the below image when we hover, in the red section it will show stop and while we hover the green section it will display running but i need that tool tip to be in default in the corresponding section without hover event..

The angular code that i used was,

```
    <canvas baseChart
        [data]="doughnutChartData"
        [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
        [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
        [colors]="colors"
        [options]="options"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
    </canvas>
```

The ts file was,

```
public doughnutChartLabels:string[] = ['Running', 'Stop', 'Idle'];
public doughnutChartData:number[] ;
public doughnutChartType:string = 'doughnut';
public colors: any[] = [{ backgroundColor: ["#008000", "#FF0000", "#FFA500"] }];
devices : Device[];
deviceLength : number;
public options:any = {
    Label: {
        display: true,
    },
    // legend: {position: 'bottom'},
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
    },
};
```

And the image contains the sections was,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISawL.png)

Here the tooltip should display in default in the red and green section even without hover over it..

Comment: which charts script  your using for pie charts??

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>